# An elementary question in singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

The following problem came up in something I am working on. It has a really elementary statement but I couldn't crack it in a couple of hours of thinking about it. It isn't clear to me if I am being dumb or I don't have the right tools to understand it. Here it goes, given the ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$ and n functions $f_i(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ (quasihomogeneous if it matters) such that the ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_i)$ is a finite dimensional local artin algebra concentrated at the origin.

Now fix an integer d and consider $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots y_n]$ with the function $ \widetilde{f}(x_i,y_i)=(\sum f_i(x_1,\ldots x_n)y_i)+p(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ for polynomials p only depending on y's whose lowest order terms have total degree at least d. Can we find a p such that this function $\widetilde{f}$ has only isolated singularities?

The answer is yes, for d=1 I believe. I am actually interested in knowing if for any collection of f's as above there is some d>1 for which we can solve the problem. If this turns out to be impossible, a nice clean condition where we can find such a p would be great too.  This problem seems open to brute force attacks, geometric interpretations, algebraic thinking (like maybe Grobner bases ?) so I am hoping someone will be able to know exactly what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is an elementary question, given that no-one has given any answer yet? :-)  More seriously, is d arbitrary or is it related to your original data?

Comment: What do you mean by "singularities"?

Comment: @Thierry d is arbitrary but the existence of a single d and a corresponding p for any collection of f's as above is what I am interested in. 

@Tom a critical point of $\tilde{f}$, that is a point in C^2n where the 2n partial derivatives simultaneously vanish.

Comment: @Thierry meant to say "a single d>1"

Comment: For a brute force but elementary approach: I would just pick $p = \sum y_i^{d}$. You have to show that the Jacobian ideal generated by the partial derivatives of $\tilde f$ has finite colength. It will suffice to show that all high powers of each $y_i$ and $f_i$ are in $J$. The Euler identity:
$$ \sum_j \frac{dF}{dx_j} x_j = (deg F)F  $$
(when $F$ homogenous) may be helpful. 

Comment: I have the same question as Tom's: What do you mean by "singularities"? Are these the points where the partial derivatives of $\tilde f$ AND $\tilde f$ vanish? Or, only the partial derivatives vanish?

Comment: @auniket Only the partial derivatives.... if this makes the problem unlikely to have an affirmative answer, a hypothesis on f_i that would make it better would be great to know!

Comment: @Hailong, That's one way to look at it. My intuition was that it was important to let p(y) vary in a family since even if p(y) is linear what allows us to find a p(y) is not that we know that any one fiber of the f_i has no singularities, it's that the set of singular fibers has measure zero. Of course, it's possible that if we let d vary and consider $\sum y_i^d$ you get somewhere but I can't see why. Can you explain a little more why you think that might work? 

Comment: Hi Daniel, if you are only concerned about the singularity at the points in the fiber over the origin, then Hailong's solution works (I think). Otherwise, there will be problems, because you only assume that the fiber over the origin is finite, and this does NOT preclude fibers over other points from becoming positive dimensional. Or, do you want to assume that $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\langle f_1 - a_1, \cdots, f_n - a_n \rangle$ is finite dimensional for ALL $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$?


Comment: That's a hypothesis I am happy to go along with if it leads to answer... I'm not convinced it's necessary by analogy with the d=1 case. I definitely care about all fibers but I'll have to write it out to understand this thing about the zero fiber. Hailong was talking about all fibers since he discussed Jacobian ideal.